# How to extract number from '78 897 dollars' without space between numbers

Tags: python, regex

I have problem with extracting number without space from string in python using regex

```
re.findall(r'\d+(?:\s)\d+','78 897 dollars')
```

expecting 78897 but i always get 78 897

Comment: By using the `\s` token, you're finding the white space as well. You're not excluding it

Comment: Extract the numbers and _then_ remove the space character. Alternatively, if the text is always a number followed by "dollars", you may use `re.sub` to replace `^(\d+)\s*(\d*) dollars$` with `\1\2`.

Comment: What's the problem with `'78 897'.replace(' ', '')`?

Answer (score 0):

try putting `.replace(" ","")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something like this.

```
import re
number = int(re.findall('[0-9]+', '78 897 dollars'.replace(' ',''))[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string with no non-digit numbers, you can use `re.sub` to remove them:

```
import re

int(re.sub(r'\D','', '78 897 dollars'))
#78897
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern that you tried with 2 capture groups, where the second part is optional.

```
\b(\d+)(?:\s(\d+))?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DxbJn3/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Rv1GSa)

```
import re

pattern = r"\b(\d+)(?:\s(\d+))?\b"
s = r"78 897 dollars"

res = re.sub(pattern, r"\1\2", s)
if res:
    print(res)
```

Output

```
78897 dollars
```